# Звуковой сигнал при изменении размера локального файла

Tags: python

У меня есть файл, при изменении его размера, подается звуковой сигнал( один раз), и код мониторит его далее на изменение нового размера и так далее по циклу. У меня в коде, при изменении размера файла, сигнал срабатывает и звучит постоянно, не могу понять в чем проблема...

```
import os, sys
import winsound

frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
duration = 5000  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
while True:
    def main():
        f = '1.txt'
        while True:
            if os.path.getsize(f) > 0:
                print("ОК")
                winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
            if os.path.getsize(f) == 0:
                print("...")
        sys.exit()
        return f
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: "ОК" в консоль он тоже спамит постоянно?

Comment: "ОК" печатает при изменении размера файла, когда файл - 0 кб. - печатает "...". постоянно, при увеличении размера файла, печатает постоянно "ОК", и сигнал непрерывно идет. Тут нужно как то функцию зациклить(файл меняется постоянно в размере, он не равен все время нулю), значит нужно делать проверку файла на +1 или как то так... я не могу понять...  **Принцип работы кода - файл изменился в размере - сигнал, изменился снова - сигнал .. и .т.д. И принты кажется лишними..!?**

Comment: добавь сон в цикл